# Spring: Does @PreAuthorize take precedence over @Cacheable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-cache

I have a question about Spring Security and Spring Caching. Say I have a method and I have annotated the method with @PreAuthorize("condition") and @Cacheable(...), like this

```
@PreAuthorize("some authorization check")
@Cacheable(....)
public String calculate() {
  ....
}
```

Does @PreAuthorize (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) take precendence over @Cacheable (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)? Does the framework guarantee that the @PreAuthorize security check will be evaluated, even if the result of the calculate() function has already been calculated and cached? Please, have in mind that this function can be called by, say, user A, then the value stored in cache, and then another user (user B) does an action that requires this function to be called again? Will the @PreAuthorize condition be evaluated or not?

From what I can find in the Spring Documenation, both @PreAuthorize and @Cacheable have the order of their advice defined as "Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE", which, I believe, means that the order in which they are evaluated is undefined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Both the `<security:global-method-security>` and `<cache:annotation-driven>` tags that enable the `@PreAuthorize` and `@Cacheable` annotations, have an `order` attribute that determines the execution precedence of their AOP advice.

If you want to ensure that the security check always happens before the cache check "on the way in", then you should give it a higher precedence by setting the `order` attribute to a lower value.

```
<security:global-method-security order="1">
```

Comment: Thanks. But isn't this something that should be mentioned in the Spring documentation on Caching? I think that ignoring other annotations on a method is pretty serious. Anyway, I already set the order attribute for both cache and global-method-security, I was just wondering if maybe the @PreAuthorize checks were executed in some other way that guarantees that they would be evaluated.